# Page renders on browsers but throws "404 page not found" for SEO crawlers and/or requests made by program. What could be the issue?

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-404

I built a site out of ZF and installed it fine on my server. I have the MVC structure and use custom routing (for SEO purposes) as below:

```
mysite.com/controller.html

mysite.com/controller/action.html
```

Generally, everything is working fine but the only problem is that SE crawlers won't find any .html files. If i open the "Activity" window from Safari, I see all the css and other files being referenced/read fine but not the page itself.

So, the page renders fine on a browser but SE crawlers or any program that made the request won't find the page. I'm wondering if it's an Apache issue. My .htaccess file is the same file that shipped with the ZF.

I really appreciate any advise/suggestions/comments!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your app is serving all pages with a 404 status code? So browsers and crawlers are getting the same thing, but the browser will render the content whereas the crawlers ignore it. I've seen some people use the Error Controller in ZF as a way of doing routing (not a good idea), where the Error Controller 'catches' all requests and then examines the params to determine what to display.

If this isn't your problem please could you edit your question to include:

- How it is you know that crawlers are getting a 404
- Some more info on how you are doing your routing

Also if you can provide an example URL we can check the headers that are being returned.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm suspecting that either zf application is sending 404 headers due to improper implementation of routing(or mobile detection) OR apache has something to do with it.
I didn't play with Error Controllers at all. It's still a same file created by ZF Tools.

Comment: 1.I'm using Google webmaster's tool to determine it's getting 404. Also, activity window from safari lists the page as "not found." 
2. I'm using Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex and match the above URLs, and specifying proper controllers and actions. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Sounds okay then. Do you get a 404 on every page - howabout something that should be matched by the default route like the homepage?  `mysite.com`. Do you have a development site you can compare so you can see if it's a server-side issue with your production setup?